# " Missing ; before statement " In a long code

Tags: javascript, date, math, lambda

I have a trouble with a long code, here is the code :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var theDateC = new Date();
    var D = (367 * theDateC.getFullYear()) - (parseInt((7 / 4)(theDateC.getFullYear + parseInt((theDateC.getMonth() + 9) / 12)))) + parseInt(275(theDateC.getMonth() / 9)) + theDateC.getDate() - 730531.5);
var L = 280.461 + 0.9856474 * D;
var M = 357.528 + 0.9856003 * D;
var Lambda = L + 1.915 * Math.sin(M) + 0.02 * Math.sin(2 * M);
var Obliquity = 23.439 - 0.0000004 * D;
var Alpha = Math.atan(Math.cos(Obliquity) * Math.tan(Lambda)); Alpha = Alpha - (360 * parseInt(Alpha / 360); Alpha = Alpha + 90 * (Math.trunc(Alpha / 90) - Math.trunc(Alpha / 90));
    var ST = 100.46 + 0.985647352 * D;
    var Dec = Math.asin(Math.sin(Obliquity) * Math.sin(Lambda));
    var Noon = Alpha - ST;
    var UTNoon = Noon - long;
    if (Date().substring(Date().length - 3, Date().length) === "GMT"
    } {
        var Zone = 0;
    } else {
        var Zone = Number(Date().substring(Date().length - 4, Date().length - 2)) + Number(Number(Date().substring(Date().length - 2, Date().length) * 60))) / 60;
};
var LocalNoon = UTNoon / 15 + Zone;
var AsrAlt = Math.atan(1 + Math.tan(lat - Dec));
var AsrArc = Math.acos((Math.sin(90 - AsrAlt) - Math.sin(Dec) * Math.sin(Lat)) / (Math.cos(Dec) * Math.cos(Lat))); AsrArc = AsrArc / 15;
var AsrTime = LocalNoon + AsrArc; alert("وقت العصر : " + AsrTime);
});
```

I know that the code is very very very long, it is for calculating Asr prayer time in the visitor's longitude & latitude (Islamic prayers), when I excute the code it's showing : **" Missing ; before statement "**.

Comment: Please edit your question to format your code.

Comment: Rather than chaining lots of calls that are difficult to debug, split it into several assignments to variables and combine the results.

Comment: If you format your code it would become a lot more readable for us to be able to help but also for you to be able to find your problem. Splitting statements so that each starts on a new line is a start. And if you have any really long lines then thing about separating them up with more local variables. Then you should be able to check the syntax of each statement much more easily to find your problem.

Comment: There is a parens missing on the first if line. (I saw this very quickly once the code was formatted.)

Comment: Before writing code please learn code formatting. This will help you track the errors easily. Otherwise you're making your as well as other's life hell.

Comment: Guys the trouble is not with formating the code, i know how to fromat the code but i still need to make the code in one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the function... check now?

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    var long = position.coords.longitude; 
    var lat = position.coords.latitude; 
    var theDateC = new Date(); 
    var D = (367*theDateC.getFullYear())-(parseInt((7/4)*(theDateC.getFullYear+parseInt((theDateC.getMonth()+9)/12))))+parseInt(275*(theDateC.getMonth()/9))+theDateC.getDate()-730531.5; 
    var L = 280.461+0.9856474*D; 
    var M = 357.528+0.9856003*D; 
    var Lambda = L +1.915*Math.sin(M)+0.02*Math.sin(2*M); 
    var Obliquity = 23.439-0.0000004*D; 
    var Alpha = Math.atan (Math.cos(Obliquity)*Math.tan(Lambda)); 
    Alpha = Alpha - (360 * parseInt(Alpha/360)); 
    Alpha = Alpha + 90 * ( Math.trunc ( Alpha / 90 ) - Math.trunc(Alpha / 90)); 
    var ST = 100.46 + 0.985647352 *D; 
    var Dec = Math.asin(Math.sin (Obliquity )*Math.sin(Lambda)); 
    var Noon = Alpha - ST; 
    var UTNoon = Noon - long; 
    if (Date().substring(Date().length - 3, Date().length) === "GMT") {
        var Zone = 0;
    } else {
        var Zone = Number(Date().substring(Date().length - 4, Date().length - 2)) + Number(Number(Date().substring(Date().length - 2, Date().length) * 60)) / 60; 
    } 
    var LocalNoon = UTNoon / 15 + Zone; var AsrAlt = Math.atan (1+ Math.tan( lat - Dec)); 
    var AsrArc = Math.acos ((Math.sin(90- AsrAlt )-Math.sin(Dec)*Math.sin(lat))/(Math.cos(Dec)*Math.cos(lat))); AsrArc = AsrArc / 15; 
    var AsrTime = LocalNoon + AsrArc; alert("وقت العصر : " + AsrTime); 
});
```

Comment: @MSCFC did it help? :)

Comment: just a minute i will try

Comment: Doesn't work, it is saying : "7/4 is not a function";

Comment: sorry for that, i found the trouble, there is a double of "(" before 7/4

Comment: it doesn't work, it's saying "7/4 is not a function" or "274 is not a function" and "bla bla bla is not a function" ...

Comment: check now sir... I have updated the function

Comment: thanks, it works correctly but it still need some edit because there are some problems in using function "getCurrentPosition", I will edit it myself.

Comment: Code-only answers aren't helpful. You should explain why the OP has their issue and how your answer fixes it. This likely should be closed as off-topic as the issue is likely caused by a simple typo.

Answer (score 0):

Special thanks To js_noob for helping me, his function works perfectly !
But I still have problems with the functions, Here is the full edited working code :

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    var long = position.coords.longitude; 
    var lat = position.coords.latitude; 
    var theDateC = new Date(); 
    var D = (367*theDateC.getFullYear())-(parseInt((7/4)*(theDateC.getFullYear+parseInt((theDateC.getMonth()+9)/12))))+parseInt(275*(theDateC.getMonth()/9))+theDateC.getDate()-730531.5; 
    var L = 280.461+0.9856474*D; 
    var M = 357.528+0.9856003*D; 
    var Lambda = L +1.915*Math.sin(M)+0.02*Math.sin(2*M); 
    var Obliquity = 23.439-0.0000004*D; 
    var Alpha = Math.atan (Math.cos(Obliquity)*Math.tan(Lambda)); 
    Alpha = Alpha - (360 * parseInt(Alpha/360)); 
    Alpha = Alpha + 90 * ( Math.trunc ( Alpha / 90 ) - Math.trunc(Alpha / 90)); 
    var ST = 100.46 + 0.985647352 *D; 
    var Dec = Math.asin(Math.sin (Obliquity )*Math.sin(Lambda)); 
    var Noon = Alpha - ST; 
    var UTNoon = Noon - long; 
    var Zone = theDateC.getTimezoneOffset();
    var LocalNoon = UTNoon / 15 + Zone; var AsrAlt = Math.atan (1+ Math.tan( lat - Dec)); 
    var AsrArc = Math.acos ((Math.sin(90- AsrAlt )-Math.sin(Dec)*Math.sin(lat))/(Math.cos(Dec)*Math.cos(lat))); AsrArc = AsrArc / 15; 
    var AsrTime = LocalNoon + AsrArc; alert("وقت العصر : " + AsrTime); 
});
```

The function is working now, but the problem is in the end.
When the alert apears it is saying : 
"وقت العصر : NaN"

As my knowledge in javascript, that means the final variable is not a number, but when i check the function i found that there no strings used !

Comment: Where you have `theDateC.getFullYear + parseInt...` you should have `theDateC.getFullYear() + parseInt...`, i.e. there are missing parenthesis after `getFullYear`. There is no need for all those calls to *parseInt*, the Date *get* methods all return numbers and mathematic operations other than `+` all convert operand values to Number.

Comment: The expression `Math.trunc( Alpha / 90 ) - Math.trunc(Alpha / 90)` must return zero, regardless of the value of *Alpha*. You seem to be working with degrees when ECMAScript mathematic functions use radians. You should state what you are trying to work out: Asr prayer can occur during a wide range of times (also varying by sect), so providing sample input and expected output helps greatly.